# Is it ok to name my baby Wahab?

Tags: naming, asma-ul-husna

I know the word wahab means all-giver, which is one of the names of God Allah. but I want to know whether it can be used for a human as a name, like Nazeer or Raheem(9:128) which can be used for humans too.

وَهَّابُ‏

Comment: It would be more appropriate to name him "Abdul Wahab" similar to Abdur Raheem or Abdur Rahman.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Abdul Wahab is a correct name. No doubt in that. But my doubt is different.